# Silverlight Data Binding a Property to an Expression of Another One or Multiple Properties

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding, properties

I've been using Flex for Flash development.  And the data binding in Flex is really powerful.

Now I'm working on a Silverlight project.  I just want to bind a control's property to an expression of another one or multiple properties.  For example:

```
<Button Name="myButton" Background="{Binding myButton.IsEnabled ? #AABBCC : #DDEEFF}" />
```

It's actually a very simple and common case.  I just want to my `myButton.Background` to be `#AABBCC` when the button is enabled, and `#DDEEFF` if disabled.

Of course, I also want to bind my `Background` property to multiple properties of other control(s).

In Flex, it's very simple.  But I don't know how to do it in Silverlight.

Thanks.

Peter

## Edits on Jan 3, 2012

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightMultiBinding.aspx
After the Silverlight 5 release and the above nice article. My needs can be done with a converter (inherits `MarkupExtension` and implements `IMultiValueConverter`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bool to color case, you need a [Converter](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx). ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx))

For the multiple binding case it is my understanding that *you can't bind to multiple values or properties*.

You will have to bind to just one property en let that property resolve the value you need.
(You can always change the property you are bound to at runtime, but you can only bind to one property at a time)

Comment: This is really limited for data binding.  If I cannot bind to multiple values or properties, I have to implement a handler for `IsEnabledChanged` event.

Comment: that is correct. have you read about commands? the CanExecute method in particular http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921126(v=pandp.20).aspx